# Better performance with many inner join (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server Stored Procedure containing many inner joins that are important for the functionality of the procedure, but they affect the performance.

Is there any other way to replace the joins and improve performance?

the code:

```
 SELECT distinct (Account.first_name + ' ' + Account.last_name) as StudentName
    FROM Account INNER JOIN  Student_Disconnection
    ON  Student_Disconnection.session_id =Account.session_id
     and Student_Disconnection.account=Account.account
    WHERE Student_Disconnection.session_id= @SessionID
    and  isnull(Student_Disconnection.account_Read,0)!=1
    End
```

Comment: Can you share your code please? It's quite hard to give an intelligent answer without more details.

Comment: its better you post your query and execution plan for better help

Comment: BTW:  how many joins in the query, and how much data in the table aprox

Comment: How do you know its the joins? It could be the `distinct`. Don't jump to any conclusions until you have the query plan. How many records does it return? how many records in each table?